# Fatal error Function name must be a string 24

Tags: string, php

Im getting this error in a linux server

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/calaniz1/public_html/system/get_answers.php on line 24

```
function print_answers($dom){

$endl = "<br />";
$html = file_get_dom($dom);
$s=2;
$answer = array();
$answer_id = array();
$count_total = 0;
$count_index = 0;
$errflag = false;
foreach ($html('.closed') as $div) {
    foreach ($div('select') as $ab){    
        $id = $ab->name;
        $count_total ++ ;
        $count_index = $count_total -1 ;
        $answer_id[$count_index] = $id;
        $answer[$count_index] = $ab->onmouseover;
    }
```

But in my computer I get no errors ...

Comment: Which line is line 24? Also please compare the php versions. You find it in the constant `echo PHP_VERSION;` - check if there are differences.

Comment: I am trying to update tag wiki's. What does your tag ganon stand for?

Answer (score 1):

I guess `file_get_dom()` returns a closure/anonymous function, or even an array with `array($object, $methodName)`. The first one is available with PHP5.3, the second one with PHP5.4. Either that, or you are doing something simply completely wrong.

After a short research: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ `$html` should be an object and what you are looking for is `$html->find('.closed')`

Wrong library, regarding the comments it is this one: http://code.google.com/p/ganon/
Bad, when everything uses the same identifiers and no namespacing ;)

Comment: @CarlosArturoAlaniz In this case my first point seems to be the interesting one: You are using an outdated version of PHP?

Comment: yep haha I forgot to check that, the server was runing o 5.2 and the library works on 5.3, allready updated it and its working. thank you all!